# Running Integration services SSIS on .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, .net-core-3.0

We are in the process of porting one WPF application to .net core and we sort of got stuck on SSIS portion. Previously we used `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` to run SSIS using this code:

```
    public void SSISUpload()
    {
        string targetServerName = "server";
        string folderName = "Project1Folder";
        string projectName = "Integration Services Project";
        string packageName = "SSISPackage/Package.dtsx";

        // Create a connection to the server
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=" + targetServerName +
            ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

        IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);
        Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];
        CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];
        ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];
        PackageInfo package = project.Packages[packageName];

        // Run the package
        package.Execute(false, null);
    }
```

However, the above references tie to .NET Framework and do not seem to have bindings for .net core or standard. We tried using [Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/), which does have standard2.0 bindings, but that does not really translate 1-1 (classes are not there) and there does not seem to be any info online on how to achieve running SSIS from .net core/standard. Anyone managed to do this?

Comment: SSIS isn't a .NET library, it's a SQL Server service. This code doesn't use SSIS, it uses *SMO* to tell SQL Server to execute a specific package. You could use a SQL statement to do the same thing - in fact, I think SMO does exactly that.

Comment: My recommendation would be to ditch SMO and just ask SQL Server to do it ([`catalog.create_execution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database), [`catalog.start_execution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-start-execution-ssisdb-database)). This is probably what SMO uses under the covers anyway (or possibly something more primitive). For most things, SMO is the poster child technology for "nice, but not really necessary, and also kinda slow".

Comment: Check [Run an SSIS package from SSMS with Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use different approaches to execute SSIS packages from C# .net core:

### Using Transact-SQL command

Instead of using  `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` you can simply use an `SQLCommand` to execute SSIS packages, as example:

```sql
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

You can refer to the following links for more information:

- [Run an SSIS package from Visual Studio Code with Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Deploy an SSIS project from Visual Studio Code with Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-tsql-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15)

### Using DTEXEC utility

Another option is to use [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.0) method to execute `DTEXEC` application, which is installed with SQL Server.As Example:

```cs
Process p = new Process();

// Redirect the output stream of the child process.

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/ISServer \"\SSISDB\Project1Folder\Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx\" /Server \"localhost\"";
p.Start();
Debug.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
```

For more information, you can refer to the following links:

- [Run an SSIS package from the command prompt with DTExec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-cmdline?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Running SSIS packages outside the Developer tools using DTEXEC.exe without installing the Integration services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/10/28/running-ssis-packages-outside-the-developer-tools-using-dtexec-exe-without-installing-the-integration-services/)
- [Kicking SSIS package off using C# program](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53923978-20bd-466e-833e-373dcc96b35b/kicking-ssis-package-off-using-c-program?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Hi, in the end we managed to utilize SQL to achieve this goal, as suggested. Thanks.